# PowerQuery - use position of column instead of column name in calculation

Tags: powerquery

New to PowerQuery and M-Code.
I have added a column with a calculation to get the max. Instead of using the hardcoded column name, I would like to use the position number of the column.

The current code is:
= Table.AddColumn(Source, "Maximum", each List.Max({[#"1-6-2021"], [#"1-5-2021"], [#"1-4-2021"]}), type number)

Instead of [#"1-6-2021"], I would like it to be column 3; for [#"1-5-2021"] column 4 etc.

How do I replace these columnnames with positions?

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Suggestion : add code fences to highlight the code and make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the {x} part for the column # you want

0 is the first column, so this is max of columns 2/3/4

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
x=  Table.AddColumn(Source, "Maximum", each List.Max({
    Record.Field(_,Table.ColumnNames(Source){1}),
    Record.Field(_,Table.ColumnNames(Source){2}),
    Record.Field(_,Table.ColumnNames(Source){3})
}), type number)
in x
```

If you need to do a Max on a bunch of columns, below would, for example, do it for all columns except the first two, which are removed by the 2nd line

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
colToSum = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),2),
AddIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source,"Index",0,1),
GetMax = Table.AddColumn(AddIndex, "Custom", each List.Max( Record.ToList( Table.SelectColumns(AddIndex,colToSum){[Index]}) ))
in GetMax
```